# The impact of different ways to call the variables in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a project about the Java Swing, one `MainFrame.java`, and other child frames triggered by the `MainFrame.java`.

The `MainFrame.java` is composed of many functions to devise the layout and add the components. However, for convenience, I put each variable in the class range and declare them with the prefix `private`, which helps me write certain function while interacting with some components that mainly be used in other functions.

Here comes the question, although the program is running smoothly. Whereas, I don't know the difference between my way and the reference way. Which one is more efficient and secure?

```java
// My way

public class MainFrame{
        private xxx variable1;
        private xxx variable2;
        ......................

        public MainFrame(){
                function1();
                function2();
                ...........
        }

        private function1(){
                ............
        }

}
```

```java
// reference way

public class MainFrame{
        ......................

        public MainFrame(){
                function1();
                function2(variable1,variable2);
                ...........
        }

        private function1(){
         xxx variable1;
         xxx variable2;
                ............
        }

}
```

Comment: If you want your variables to be accessible across class methods, use your way, if not you can use reference way. Difference is of just of scope i.e. in your way, variables memory will not be free until your class's object is GC'd. Whereas in reference way, variables memory will be freed after method execution is complete. I don't think there is any other difference in both ways.

Comment: 1) *"other child frames"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the situation but typically you want to reduce the scope as much as you can. For example if you are creating expensive objects that could be reused between method calls you might move that object on the class level.